# PyCharm cannot run R console

Tags: r, pycharm

I am totally new to PyCharm, I tried to one of my R projects in PyCharm to be able to push it to Git and managed with that. I have installed the R language for IntelliJ plugin and it seems it recognized the code as it is colored correctly but it won't run the code, giving me the error:

`Unsuported interpreter version 4.2.1`

After Googling a bit I am not closer to fixing this, does anybody have an idea?

[image]